# rails VersionCake versioning multiple APIs independently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version, versioncake

I have a rails application that provides 2 sets of APIs. Say /api/investor/... and /api/borrower/...I am using VerisonCake to manage the API versions. VersionCake has a configuration to specify the supported versions:

```
config.versioncake.supported_version_numbers = (1...4)
```

As far as I can tell this is a global setting. Is there a way to specify different supported version numbers for each set of APIs?

Regards,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

[Version Cake v3](https://github.com/bwillis/versioncake/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#300-aug-3-2015) introduced individually versioning different resources with supported, deprecated or obsolete version number. Check out the documentation in the [readme](https://github.com/bwillis/versioncake#versioned-resources).